# WLAN: Can connect to AP but not to network

Tags: wireless

I'm tryin to connect to the internet using my Thinkpad T60 running Ubuntu 11.04 via my WLAN router (a FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7270 configured to use WPA-PSK).

This is no problem using a *wired* connection to the router, so I know that the router's connection to the internet is not the problem.

I can also connect to my router using `wpa_supplicant`:

```
# wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -cwpasupplicant.conf -Dwext
Trying to associate with 00:21:fe:05:13:b3 (SSID='foobar' freq=2412 MHz)
Associated with 00:21:fe:05:79:b3
WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:21:fe:05:79:b3 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:21:fe:05:79:b3 completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]
```

`iwconfig` shows that I'm indeed connected:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"foobar"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:21:FE:05:79:B3   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:19   Missed beacon:0
```

Here's the output of `ifconfig`:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:57:2e:2f:2d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:77ff:fe2e:2f2d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3142 (3.1 KB)  TX bytes:36573 (36.5 KB)
```

Also, if I connect to my router using a wired connection and then run the `wpa_supplicant` call above I can access the router's status page (over the wired connection) which then shows my laptop as being connected via WLAN, too.

However, if I only run that `wpa_supplicant` command without any cables attached, then I get no access to the network. I can't ping the router via its static ip:

```
# ping 192.168.178.1
connect: Network is unreachable
```

The end of the output of `dmesg` is

```
[ 3903.459642] wlan0: associated
[ 3903.461648] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 3913.712125] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Could this be a IPv4 vs. IPv6 problem? How do I continue debugging this? Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just upgraded my router's firmware, and this seems to have solved the problem.